# RestFB: Getting list of users who liked a post

Tags: restfb

I need to get the name of each like on each post on a group page. Since I first have to get some data from the original post, I'm trying to make a connection then iterate through the likes and get a list of the users who liked each post. Here's what I have:

```
Connection<Likes> feedLikes = postFeed.fetchConnection(id+"/likes", Likes.class, Parameter.with("fields","from,actions,type"));
                    // Get the iterator
                    Iterator<List<Likes>> likeIt = feedLikes.iterator();
                    while(likeIt.hasNext()) {
                        List<Likes> likeFeed = likeIt.next();
                        for (Likes currLike: likeFeed) {
                            String ObjectId = id;
                            String LikeUserId = currLike.getId();
                            String LikeUserName = currLike.getName();
                            like_data.add(new String[] {ObjectId, LikeUserId, LikeUserName});
                        }
                    }
```

This doesn't work and I'm a little stuck on why. I know the username is stored in Likes.LikeItem but I can't even get to that step so far. Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Facebook reference this is not possible (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/likes):

> A User or Page can only query their own likes. Other Users'or Pages' likes are unavailable due to privacy concerns.
>
> Only aggregated counts using `total_count` with the `summary` parameter are available for Post likes.

Comment: Thank you. Is that still true in the sense of seeing who liked a post on a page? I'm not trying to generate all of the users "likes"; rather, trying to see who liked a post on my page.

Comment: You can only see on a Post how many likes you have (or better check the reactions) and if you (as user or page) liked your Post you can see this, too. But you won't get a list of all users who liked this post. The only way to build up a list, is a webhook and realtime notifications. But then you have to handle the information on your server and it is a bit more complicated. And you can only get information about new likes, not the likes in the past.

Comment: If I was able to get my groups users to give permission, however, would I be able to see the posts they've liked in the group?

Comment: According to the Facebook docs you can only see your own likes.